# Data annotation to clean field before posting

Tags: c#, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an MVC C# application working and all is good, however, I have just found something bad.

I have a form that allows input text. Of course, that input text is rendered using an HTML helper.

The corresponding model field is something like this:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe tener como máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Well... as I said, it works, however, when I enter `<` in the form field, this error occus:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Nombre=&quot;&lt;Normal&quot;).`

And the form is not actually submitted.

The question is: is there already a data annotation filter that allows me to strip dangerous characters automatically, before posting? If not, how can I create one? Should I add an annotation filter at class or property level? If at property level, I will need to go through all model classes adding the attribute to the string properties. Maybe I could create an action filter also, but I think this could be insecure if the site is actually being attacked.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Please state how this question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: @CaiusJard is not duplicate

Comment: @IanKemp that does not answer. I don't want to configure validate request to false because that will be insecure. As I asked, I need to allow the request, but before posting the model, content should be cleaned when it is string. I am thinking about adding an attribute to each string field, so that, before posting, all dangerous characters will be removed.

Comment: Notice also that those fields are not for storing HTML. I have other fields for HTML and I have implemented solutions from those posts, but most of string fields are not for storing HTML.That is why I need to remove or replace entities. For example, if user enters `<` in the field, that character should be removed or replaced by `&lt;`, and so on.